# How do you pass parameters which are not associated with a serializer field in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, rest

I have a form with fields which are not associated with a model.  I assume to implement the equivalent using a REST API (django-rest-framework), I would have to pass those additional fields, which are not associated with a Serializer?  How do I do that?

Let's say the additional field is number_of_pages.  I use that for some calculation.  How do I allow that to be passed in my REST call?

Comment: which Rest frame work are you using `django-tastypie`  `django-rest-framework`  or some other frame work? If you are using `django-tastypie` then `hydrate` method is what you are looking after

Comment: django-rest-framework

Answer (score 3):

if you are using `ModelSerializer` from DjangoRestFramework, just add a field.

by default only model fields are added, but nothing limits you to add more, the only thing that may be problematic (but I've not tested it) - you may have too many fields while creating or updating model - in such a case, you will need to remove those fields in `create()` and `update()` methods before calling `save()`.

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    number_of_pages = fields.IntegerField()

    # this I'm not sure if needed
    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data.pop('number_of_pages')
        return super(MyModelSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

    def update(self,instance, validated_data):
        validated_data.pop('number_of_pages')
        return super(MyModelSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
    # end

    class Meta:
        fields = ('mymodelfield_1', 'mymodelfield_2', 'number_of_pages')
        model = MyModel
```

Comment: This `fields` is from `django.db.models`?

Comment: It seems to missed something. I get error:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name 'number_of_pages' is not valid for model 'MyModel'.`

Comment: Ok, it works. In my case, however, the extra field is optional, so I added `required=False` in the declaration of the extra field, like would be in `number_of_pages = fields.IntegerField(required=False)`, but the field type is boolean, so specifically for me, I did `default=fields.BooleanField(required=False)`. Don't doing this I get error: `'QuestionnaireLanguage' object has no attribute 'is_default'.`

Answer (score 0):

If, you are using `django-rest-framework`, then you can use `SerializerMethodField()` to pass additional fields in Api. Below I give an example.

```
class UserGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""
    This Serializer pass additionl field count. by using SerializerMethodField()
"""
count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = UserGroup

def get_count(self,obj):
    """return length of group"""
    return Groupmember.objects.filter(user_group=obj.id).count()
```

and use

```
serializer_class = UserGroupSerializer
```

in view.

I think it can help you.

Thanks

Comment: How will I pass the data if I call the rest api?  What will the json look like?

Comment: you are using djnago-rest-framework ?. and what your requirement.  If you are using django-rest-framework please look into this link. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

Comment: which data you want to pass in api call ?